# Detecting ID Card on different Backgrounds (HSV and Canny Methods)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

i am currently working on a project which in some part includes card detection. I implemented two methods for this; one with Canny edge detection, and one with calling inRange function on HSV image.

Canny function:

```
void DetectWithCanny(cv::Mat inputImage){
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contoursVec;
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(13, 13));
const int lowThresh = 100;
const int ratio=3;
const int kernelSize =3;
cv::Mat detected;
 
 cv::imshow("resized", inputImage);
cv::blur(inputImage, inputImage, cv::Size(3, 3));
cv::imshow("blurred", inputImage);
cv::Canny(inputImage, detected, 100,  300 , kernelSize);
cv::imshow("canny edges", detected);
cv::morphologyEx(detected, detected, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
cv::imshow("closed", detected);

cv::findContours(detected, contoursVec, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
contoursVec = removeContours(contoursVec); //Removes unneccesary contours.
cv::drawContours(inputImage, contoursVec, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
cv::imshow("contours", inputImage);

cv::waitKey(0);
```

HSV function:

```
cv::Mat detectCardHsv(cv::Mat inputImage){
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(13, 13));
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contoursVec;
cv::Mat resizedImage;
cv::Mat threshold; 
cv::Mat clone = inputImage.clone();
resizedImage = clone;

cv::medianBlur(resizedImage, resizedImage, 15);
cv::imshow("blurred", resizedImage);
cv::Mat hsvMap;
cv::cvtColor(resizedImage, resizedImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
cv::Scalar lowerWhite = cv::Scalar(0,0,55);
cv::Scalar upperWhite = cv::Scalar(60,60,255);
cv::inRange(resizedImage, lowerWhite, upperWhite, hsvMap);
cv::imshow("hsv", hsvMap);
cv::threshold(hsvMap, threshold, 10, 255, 1);
cv::imshow("thresh", threshold);
cv::morphologyEx(threshold, threshold, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
cv::imshow("closed", threshold);
cv::findContours(threshold, contoursVec, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
std::cout<< "Contours size before elimination: "<<contoursVec.size();
contoursVec = removeContours(contoursVec);
std::cout<< "Contours size after elimination: "<<contoursVec.size();   
cv::drawContours(clone, contoursVec, -1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
return clone;
```

(Note: This is my local playground just for testing, i know there are lot of unneccesary or deficient variables or performance issues, its completely fine and will be gone while implementing.)

However, in some images; HSV method fails, end Canny method succeeds. Trying two methods on an image does not seem suitable for me, (i.e. calling canny if hsv method doesn't give desired output after some tries.) I am certain i am missing something(s) with HSV method.

It's my first time using hue saturation value (HSV) channel,so `lowerBound = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 55);` and `upperBound = cv::Scalar(60, 60, 50);` values are completely random.

I also would love to implement this detection with using only Hue channel of HSV image, since it is less dependent on light/brightness, but it's my next step.

There are my input and output images, first two are my source images. ( medianBlurred with 15 kernel size, since they're real identity cards i couldn't provide raw images.) last two are outputs of HSV functions with different input.

[image: Input image with dark colored background]

[image: Input image with light colored background]

[image: Output of HSV method]

[image: Output of Canny method]

Thanks for your help. Stay healthy, stay home :)

Comment: it can be better sharing source images so we can try too

Comment: Yeah, do share source images. And also try adding erode and dilate along with blurring.. that will help in skipping the text and other things while detecting the cards

Comment: Hey, thanks for comments and sorry for not providing source images before, obviously i can not share raw images but i'm uploading blurred versions (with 15 kernelsize ) of them now.

Comment: I dont think it is possible using opencv to detect id card on every background with 100% accuracy. I would suggest you to go for object detection using tensorflow. This task is achievable using only deeplearning.

Comment: What is `removeContours` doing in there ? You can not find an easy segmentation algorithm which can work for every conditions. You should play with the parameters for each situation. Or there should at least one reference such as: constant light values, distance taking picture, size of object etc.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk removeContours is deleting unwanted vectors in contoursVector by checking their shape factors and bounding boxes' aspect ratio. I'm sure i can't develop an algorithm that works in all cases, i am planning on creating an enum class and switch/case structure to detect features of image then use different parameters on each feature. If you were me, what would you change to obtain clear contour of the card in image with white background? (Using HSV Colorspace and inRange method.) Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: Is this supposed to work for any card? Or are you looking at solving this for a particular type of ID card? If it's the latter case, you can try to detect the boundary of the small rectangular golden patch instead of the boundaries of the full card. Once you have that, you can do some processing to infer the actual boundaries. This would make it robust to background differences. But in general, I agree with @astrick that this probably needs deep learning.

Comment: @Ananda hey, i did that "golden patch" method yesterday and works way better than detecting whole card first, thanks. I needed a quick solution for this case due to lack of time. Sadly building tensorflow libraries for cross platform with CMake will take some time to implement.

Comment: @astrick you cannot be wrong more. object detection is a problem that's been worked on for a very long time, long before deep learning got so popular. and even with deep learning, you won't be able to achieve 100% accuracy anyway.

Comment: @gumeykayim I am suggesting that deeplearning can be used here to increase the accuracy of detection. I already know that it cannot give you 100% but more than 90% is achievable while in case of opencv only 50-60% accuracy is expected.